# pandas loop through a list of dataframes (df) to do calculation, results in previous df to be referenced and used for next df

Tags: python, pandas, loops

This is an example for what I’m trying to do, I have two dfs (actually 100+), the ‘r_results’ with value=1 calculated in the first df will be subject to a different threshold in next df as in the ‘buffer_screen’, however I got stuck when I’m trying to reference the ‘r_results’ from previous ‘processed’ df for next raw df for calculation. hope I’m making myself clear.

For all dfs I have, the calculation will be done in order, i.e., the results in first df will be used in the second one, so on so forth until the calculation is done for all dfs.

Code example as below for the calculation in the first df, then 'buffer_screen' function will be used for next dfs in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],
                'r_f':[0.18878187,0.327355797,0.100753051]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                'r_f':[0.300009355,0.331788473,0.146077926,0.167329833,0.245227094]})
df_lst = [df1, df2]

thd_new = 0.3
thd_curr = 0.3333

def buffer_screen(curr, r):
    if curr==1 and r<=thd_curr:
        return 1
    elif curr==0 and r<=thd_new:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for df in df_lst[0:1]:
    df_new = df.assign(r_results = lambda X: X['r_f'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x <= thd_new else 0))
```

Comment: What should be the final result?

Comment: Final results would be the 'r_results' from all dfs. These are time series dfs, one df for one day, I would need to find the final results for all days in this time series.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output with 0 and 1 for df1 and df2?

Comment: The expected output in df1 for all IDs are 1,0,1, in df2 for all IDs are 1,0,1,1,1

The basic logic would be:

If r_results of the ID in previous df is 1, compare to thd_curr
elif r_results of the ID in previous df is 0, compare to thd_new
else compare to thd_new

Last scenario can be an ID not in previous df.

df1 is the starting point to determine initial r_results, where all r_f compared to thd_new, in the rest of the dfs, using above logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to compare the ID of the current dataframe to a threshold. This threshold is `thd_new` if in the previous dataframe the result was 0 (default) or `thd_curr` if the result was 1. So you need to build a dictionary of threshold for each ID:

```
thd = {}
for df in df_lst:
    m = df['r_f'].le(df['ID'].map(thd).fillna(thd_new).values).astype(int)
    df['r_results'] = m
    thd |= dict(zip(df['ID'], np.where(m, thd_curr, thd_new)))
    print(df, end='\n\n')

# Output
   ID       r_f  r_results
0   1  0.188782          1
1   2  0.327356          0
2   3  0.100753          1

   ID       r_f  r_results
0   1  0.300009          1
1   2  0.331788          0
2   3  0.146078          1
3   4  0.167330          1
4   5  0.245227          1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, can you elabrate a bit more about the df['r_results'] = m part? I'm trying to run the code in spyder and it indicated name 'm' is not defined.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code resolved the issue for the example. Actually I’m asking this way to reference data from previous processed df because the calculation is a bit more complicated and involved more data but my code is too long to be put here. In detail, there are 4 data points:

Comment: i_f, r_f1, r_f2 and r_f3, the first i_f compares to threshold of 0.95 (get IDs great than or equal to), the three r_fs compare to 0.3 (get IDs less than or equal to), four comparison results together determine eligible IDs, in next df, do the same thing, i_f compares to threshold of 0.95, however the three r_fs, as the example, eligible IDs from previous DF compare to 0.3333, others compare to 0.3, again together determine final IDs in this DF, so on so forth.

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],
                    'i_f':[0.967385562,0.869575345,1],
                    'r_f1':[0.18878187,0.327355797,0.100753051],
                    'r_f2':[0.047237449,0.056038276,0.189434048],
                    'r_f3':[0.095283998,0.2554309,0.138240321]})

Comment: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                    'i_f':[0.985,1,0.993297332,1,1],
                    'r_f1':[0.300009355,0.331788473,0.146077926,0.167329833,0.245227094],
                    'r_f2':[0.152293038,0.06668,0.196683885,0.101269411,0.02493159],
                    'r_f3':[0.111617815,0.042016,0.175285158,0.085330897,0.238370325]})

Comment: The expected output in df1 for all IDs are 1,0,1, in df2 for all IDs are 1,0,1,1,1.