# pandas loop through a list of dataframes to do calculation

Tags: python, pandas, loops

This is related to another query ([pandas loop through a list of dataframes (df) to do calculation, results in previous df to be referenced and used for next df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744423/pandas-loop-through-a-list-of-dataframes-df-to-do-calculation-results-in-prev)), while with more specific details about when looping a list of dataframes(dfs), the calculation is with dependency between the two continuous dfs.

Calculation Requirement: i_f, r_f1, r_f2 and r_f3 in dfs, i_f compares to threshold of 0.95 (get IDs great than or equal to), the three r_fs compare to 0.3 (get IDs less than or equal to), four comparison results together determine eligible IDs in the first df, in next df, do the same thing, i_f compares to the same threshold of 0.95, however for the three r_fs, eligible IDs from previous DF compare to 0.3333, others compare to 0.3, again together determine eligible IDs in this df, so on so forth for the rest of the df in the list.

below is the df list examples and expected output in df1 for all IDs are 1,0,1, in df2 for all IDs are 1,0,1,1,1.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],
                    'i_f':[0.967385562,0.869575345,1],
                    'r_f1':[0.18878187,0.327355797,0.100753051],
                    'r_f2':[0.047237449,0.056038276,0.189434048],
                    'r_f3':[0.095283998,0.2554309,0.138240321]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                    'i_f':[0.985,1,0.993297332,1,1],
                    'r_f1':[0.300009355,0.331788473,0.146077926,0.167329833,0.245227094],
                    'r_f2':[0.152293038,0.06668,0.196683885,0.101269411,0.02493159],
                    'r_f3':[0.111617815,0.042016,0.175285158,0.085330897,0.238370325]})
df_lst = [df1, df2]`
```

Comment: sorry about that. actually all desire are included in this single question, you can ignore the first paragraph if that is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is the same as your previous question. The threshold `i_f` is constant so this is not a problem unlike `r_f*` which must be calculated at each iteration. However the threshold is the same for all `r_f*`:

```
for df in df_lst:
    # boolean mask for i_f
    m1 = df['i_f'].ge(0.95)

    # boolean masks for r_f*
    m2 = df.filter(like='r_f').le(df['ID'].map(thd).fillna(0.3).values, axis=0)

    # compute the final result
    res = (m1 & m2.all(axis=1)).astype(int)
    df['r_results'] = res

    # update the threshold dictionary for each group
    thd |= dict(zip(df['ID'], np.where(res, 0.33, 0.3)))
    print(df, end='\n\n')

# Output
   ID       i_f      r_f1      r_f2      r_f3  r_results
0   1  0.967386  0.188782  0.047237  0.095284          1
1   2  0.869575  0.327356  0.056038  0.255431          0
2   3  1.000000  0.100753  0.189434  0.138240          1

   ID       i_f      r_f1      r_f2      r_f3  r_results
0   1  0.985000  0.300009  0.152293  0.111618          1
1   2  1.000000  0.331788  0.066680  0.042016          0
2   3  0.993297  0.146078  0.196684  0.175285          1
3   4  1.000000  0.167330  0.101269  0.085331          1
4   5  1.000000  0.245227  0.024932  0.238370          1
```

Comment: this resolved the issue, much much appreciated!

Comment: @Silvia. Sorry for my late response. I saw your new question. I tried to give a generic answer. I hope this will be useful!